# xmr stack cpu closes without any error

Tags: cpu-mining

When I open the program it simply closes without returning any messages. What can I do?

Intel Xeon CPU E5-2640 v3 2.60Ghz Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2):

Make sure it isn't blocked by an antivirus (including Windows Defender), that would be the usual cause.